# textarea autoresize function not working on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a function that resizes textareas as they are typed in

```
function textarea_resize() {
    //  changes mouse cursor when highlighting loawer right of box
    $("textarea.autoresize").on('keyup', function(e) {
        var myPos = $(this).offset();
        myPos.bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        myPos.right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
        
        if (myPos.bottom > e.pageY && e.pageY > myPos.bottom - 16 && myPos.right > e.pageX && e.pageX > myPos.right - 16) {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "nw-resize" });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "" });
        }
    })
    //  the following simple make the textbox "Auto-Expand" as it is typed in
    .keyup(function(e) {
        //  this if statement checks to see if backspace or delete was pressed, if so, it resets the height of the box so it can be resized properly
        if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
            $(this).height(parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) != 0 ? parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) : parseFloat($(this).css("font-size")));
        }
        //  the following will help the text expand as typing takes place
        var new_height = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
        if( $(this).outerHeight() < new_height ) {
            $(this).height(new_height);
        }
    });
    
    $('textarea.autoresize').trigger('keyup');
}
```

Which I call on page load:

```
textarea_resize();
```

And I apply a class of `autoresize` to each textarea to apply it.

This works when I type in each textarea, it'll resize automatically but on page load it is keeping the textareas extremely small.

Comment: Looks fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/qmwhe9a5/

Comment: Make sure your Script is not executed before the Dom is ready